Glow following cursor in html or css
I have this example website here: https://jars.vexyhost.com/
And i want to ask what is called this glow that follow cursor when you hover cards from page?
And on second example here: https://www.areacs.ro/
The web following cursor...
What is that called?
If possible to help with how to do it too is ok, if not at least with the name of thing and i can look on google. Thank you!
I tried look on google for something similar but i couldnt find it at all

Anyone? Still nobody after a week ?

I think this site is dead right ?
